# Difficult limits question

Tags: limits, contest-math, limits-without-lhopital, indeterminate-forms

I'm prepping for this entrance exam called the JEE Advanced(An Exam in India) and I found this in the previous year papers. I've noticed that the L'Hopital rule doesn't work here nor expanding $\cos x$ or $e$, nor could I factorise or use the sandwich theorem. I just couldn't get anywhere. Would really appreciate if you gave me some tips on the thought process of solving limits questions and how to proceed when you see a limits question.

The question:
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^{\cos{x^n}} - e}{x^m}= -\frac{e}{2}$$
Then find $\frac{m}{n}$. Thanks in advance!

PS: I didn't know how to use mathmetical symbols here. Hope you understand the question.

Comment: Does the question contain: $e^{\cos (x^n)}$ or $e^{\cos^n(x)}$?

Comment: You may get more answers if you use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question.

Comment: @Vizag it's cos(x^n)

Comment: @robjohn noted thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose $n,m$ are positive integers.

As $x \to 0$ we have:
\begin{align}
\cos(x^n) &= 1 - \frac{x^{2n}}{2} + O(x^{4n})
\\
e^{\cos(x^n)} &= e e^{-x^{2n}/2+O(x^{4n})}
= e\left(1-\frac{x^{2n}}{2}+O(x^{4n})\right)
= e-\frac{e x^{2n}}{2}+O(x^{4n})
\\
e^{\cos(x^n)} - e &= -\frac{e x^{2n}}{2}+O(x^{4n})
\\
\frac{e^{\cos(x^n)} - e}{x^m} &= -\frac{e x^{2n-m}}{2}+O(x^{4n-m})
\end{align}
So to get limit $-e/2$ we need $2n-m = 0$.  That is: $m=2n$ so $\frac{m}{n} = 2$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what O(x^4n) means and on the thought process

Comment: @Kaustav Other terms in the expansion, which are of the order of $4n$ or higher.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $m, n$ to be positive we can see that the numerator of the expression under limit is of the form $A-B$ where both $A, B$ tend to $e$. Then we can rewrite it as $$B((A/B) - 1)$$ Clearly $A/B\to 1$ and hence if $$t=\log(A/B)=\log A-\log B\to 0$$ and we can write $A/B=\exp(t) $. Thus $B((A/B) - 1)$ can be rewritten as $$B(\exp(t) - 1)=B\cdot\frac{\exp(t)-1}{t}\cdot t=B\cdot\frac{\exp(\log A-\log B) - 1}{\log A-\log B} \cdot(\log A-\log B) $$ Now $B\to e$ and the fraction in middle above tends to $1$ and hence the given limit condition implies $$\lim_{x\to 0}e\cdot\frac{\cos x^n-1}{x^m}=-\frac{e}{2}$$ which further leads to $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos x^n} {x^m} =\frac{1}{2}$$ The expression under limit above can be written as $$\frac{1-\cos x^n} {x^{2n}}\cdot\frac{x^{2n}}{x^m}$$ and the first fraction tends to $1/2$. It follows that we have $$\lim_{x\to 0}x^{2n-m}=1$$ which is possible only when $m=2n$ and thus $m/n=2$.

There is no need of any advanced tools like LHospital or Taylor series.

Comment: Excellent answer; I was looking for a limits based approach to this question without invoking Taylor series or L'Hopital's rule. However, I would like to see the first part of the answer(about the $A-B$ form) to be more elaborated.

Comment: @Manan: I have edited my answer to provide more steps. The key idea is the use of limit $$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\exp(t)-1}{t}=1$$ This allows us to reduce a factor of the form $A-B$ to $B(\log A-\log B) $. The only condition is that both $A, B$ tend to same non-zero limit.

Comment: @Manan: This is one of my favorite techniques which I have used extensively on this website. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3194658/72031), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3221341/72031) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3103521/72031).

Comment: This definitely seems to be a reasonably simple method to solve a lot of apparently-complicated limits.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Use Taylor's expansion of the numerator: $\;\cos x^n=1-\dfrac {x^{2n}}2+o(x^{2n})$, so
$$\mathrm e^{\cos x^n}=\mathrm e^{1-\tfrac {x^{2n}}2+o(x^{2n})}=\mathrm e\Bigl(1-\frac {x^{2n}}2+o(x^{2n})\Bigr).$$
Can you proceed?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what taylor expansion is

Comment: You never had a course on Taylor's formula??

Comment: No I'm from india and still in high school do they teach you this in high school?

Comment: In high school, it's a different problem. Here, they use the linear approximation of functions with the equation of the tangent  (1st order approximation), which   is the simplest version of Taylor's formula.

Comment: Didn't really get that but thanks anyway

Comment: @Kaustav  Here is a link to what you might think helpful

Comment: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/TaylorSeries.aspx                         The taylor series is an infinite series estimating the original function, such as sin, cos, log, e, ..etc on a certain point. When the point is at 0, it is called a mclaurin series. It is extremely helpful as you could just substitute some of the terms in the mclaurin series in the limit, and it works.      For example, the first and the second term in the mclaurin series is 1+x, and if you substitute in those values to a limit where x goes to 0, it would work.

Comment: And yes, they teach this in highschool (specifically BC cal)  :)

Comment: @user547075 they don't teach us shit here. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

$$l = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{\cos(x^n)}-e}{x^m} = -\frac{e}{2}$$

Applying L'hopital's rule,

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-e^{\cos(x^n)}\cdot\sin(x^n)\cdot nx^{n-1}}{mx^{m-1}} = -\frac{e}{2}$$
$$-\frac{n}{m}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{ e^{\cos(x^n)}\cdot\sin(x^n)}{x^{m-n}} = -\frac{e}{2}$$

$$\frac{n}{m}\lim_{x\to0} e^{\cos(x^n)}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x^n)}{x^{m-n}} = \frac{e}{2}$$

$$\frac{n}{m}\cdot e\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x^n)}{x^{m-n}} = \frac{e}{2}$$

Now, $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x^n)}{x^{m-n}} = 1 $ if $m-n=n$ or $m =2n$

So,

$$\frac{n}{m}\cdot e\cdot1 = \frac{e}{2}$$

Again it follows $m=2n$

So, $$\frac{m}{n} = 2$$

Answer (score 0):

L'Hospital works here actually.

$$\lim_{x->0} \frac{e^{\cos(x^n)} - e}{x^m} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-nx^{n-1}\sin(x^n)e^{\cos(x^n)}}{mx^{m-1}} = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{-nx^{n}\sin(x^n)e^{\cos(x^n)}}{mx^{m}}$$

Now, divide nominator and denominator by $x^{m-n}$ in order to have $x^n$ in denominator (Then we can use the property $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x^n)}{x^n} = 1$)

$$ = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{-nx^{2n-m}\sin(x^n)e^{\cos(x^n)}}{mx^{n}} = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{-nx^{2n-m}e}{m} = -\frac{e}{2} \implies \lim_{x \to 0}x^{2n-m} = \frac{m}{2n}$$ 
$$\implies m = 2n \text{ or } m = 0$$

But in $m = 0$ case, the first expression has a limit not equal to $-\frac{e}{2}$. So $m = 2n$.